# iOS - dSYMs for re-signed app

Tags: ios, crashlytics, dsym, xcarchive

I'm working on an branded application for customers. 
In order to automate the signature branding part I developed a script that the customer can run to resign the generated xcArchive with her/his certificates and provisionings and then upload it to the App Store.

In the project build phase, I am running scripts to submit the dSYMs to Crashlytics (I have access to the customers' keys).
Will the dSYMs be of any use after the application is resigned and its bundle id gets modified?

Answer (score 0):

After you resign and change the bundle ID is that app appearing in the Fabric Crashlytics dashboard?

dSYMs are tied to organization API keys and not bundle IDs, so as long as the app appears in Fabric under the same organization, the dSYMs will get associated with the app and crashes will be symbolicated.